# List of homescreen icons

Tags: android

Is there a way to get a list of all the icons on the homescreen?

I'm adding shortcuts, but I want to check to verify that there aren't existing ones.

Comment: If it's a widget, you can check to see if a widget already exists and cancel the create. For an app, see the statement above.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible, unless you design your own launcher to do this