# Is it possible to see which apps are currently on a users home screen?

Tags: android

I'm wondering if it's possible to see which shortcuts and widgets are on a users home screen, and what size they are.

**I'm not trying to delete shortcuts or in any way change the users home screen.**

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302494/list-of-homescreen-icons

Comment: Thanks. Tried searching, since I knew I couldn't be the first one to wonder, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Its not possible. But if you design your own launcher then you can put this logic in it :)

Comment: saying *No* is always very quick :p anyhow, you're welcome :)

Comment: Hehe, that's true. It's appreciated though, to get shot down early - before I start thinking about all the awesome stuff I would do. Can't accept for another 30 seconds. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, its launcher depended...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Waqas was 32 seconds faster than you. :(